# How to set an android app to use socket.io in ssl?

Tags: android, ssl, socket.io

I am using a library for [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) to make an app for android. I have managed to get the app to communicate with a nginx + node.js machine. I am now interested in using SSL for the length of the connection, but cannot seem to get it to work. I think I can figure out the nginx end, but I am having some issue with the android part. I notice that the website contained the following:

```
// default SSLContext for all sockets
IO.setDefaultSSLContext(mySSLContext);
IO.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier);

// set as an option
opts = new IO.Options();
opts.sslContext = mySSLContext;
opts.hostnameVerifier = myHostnameVerifier;
socket = IO.socket("https://localhost", opts);
```

I only changed the http to an https, I am assuming I need to do more here, but I have no idea what the rest of this bit of code means, what are the objects `mySSLContext` and `myHostnameVerifier` and how would I generate them?